# Slim html entity un-escape

Tags: slim-lang

I want [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/) to unescape an HTML entity. How should I do it?

### Example output:

```
<b>&times;</b>
```

Comment: Are you just looking to parse the DOM?

Answer (score 3):

This would unescape html entity in Slim:

```
b == ("&times")
```